# How to install a CA in Minikube so image pulls are trusted

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry

I want to use Minikube for local development. It needs to access my companies internal docker registry which is signed w/ a 3rd party certificate.

Locally, I would copy the cert and run `update-ca-trust extract` or `update-ca-certificates` depending on the OS.

For the Minikube vm, how do I get the cert installed, registered, and the docker daemon restarted so that `docker pull` will trust the server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As best as I can tell, there is no way to do this. The next best option is to use the insecure-registry option at startup.

```
minikube --insecure-registry=foo.com:5000
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to do something similar recently.   You should be able to just hop on the machine with minikube ssh and then follow the directions here

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/#understanding-the-configuration

to place the CA in the appropriate directory (/etc/docker/certs.d/[registry hostname]/).  You shouldn't need to restart the daemon for it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the minikube has a feature to copy all the contents of `~/.minikube/files` directory to its VM filesystem. So you can place your certificates under

```
~/.minikube/files/etc/docker/certs.d/<docker registry host>:<docker registry port> path
```

and these files will be copied into the proper destination on minikube startup automagically.

Comment: saved my bacon, i needed the ca.crt, domain.cert and domain.key in that folder. thanks!

Comment: Is this behavior true when using Docker as the VM as well?

Answer (score 1):

Shell into Minikube.

Copy your certificates to:

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/<docker registry host>:<docker registry port>
```

Ensure that your permissions are correct on the certificate, they must be at least readable.

Restart Docker (systemctl restart docker)

Don't forget to create a secret if your Docker Registry uses basic authentication:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry service-registry --docker-server=<docker registry host>:<docker registry port> --docker-username=<name> --docker-password=<pwd> --docker-email=<email>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should copy your root certificate to `$HOME/.minikube/certs` and restart the minikube with `--embed-certs` flag.

For more details please refer to minikube handbook: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/untrusted_certs/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [`ImagePullSecrets`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod).

You can create a secret with your cert and let your pod use it.

Comment: If it is possible to put a certificate in a secret, it isn't documented. Additionally, the certificate is normally installed on the base os and then the docker daemon restarted. In the minikube case, this would be the daemon on the vm.

Answer (score 0):

By starting up the minikube with the following :

```
minikube start --insecure-registry=internal-site.dev:5244
```

It will start the docker daemon with the `--insecure-registry` option :

```
/usr/local/bin/docker daemon -D -g /var/lib/docker -H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 --label provider=virtualbox --insecure-registry internal-site.dev:5244 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/var/lib/boot2docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/var/lib/boot2docker/server.pem --tlskey=/var/lib/boot2docker/server-key.pem -s aufs
```

but this expects the connection to be HTTP. Unlike in the [Docker registry documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/) Basic auth does work, but it needs to be placed in a `imagePullSecret` from the [Kubernetes docs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod).

I would also recommend reading "Adding imagePulSecrets to service account" (link on the page above) to get the secret added to all pods as they are deployed. Note that this will not impact already deployed pods.

Answer (score 0):

One option that works for me is to run a k8s job to copy the cert to the minikube host...

This is what I used to trust the harbor registry I deployed into my minikube

```
cat > update-docker-registry-trust.yaml << END
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
name: update-docker-registry-trust
namespace: harbor
spec:
template:
    spec:
    containers:
    - name: update
        image: centos:7
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args: ["find /etc/harbor-certs; find /minikube; mkdir -p /minikube/etc/docker/certs.d/core.harbor-${MINIKUBE_IP//./-}.nip.io; cp /etc/harbor-certs/ca.crt /minikube/etc/docker/certs.d/core.harbor-${MINIKUBE_IP//./-}.nip.io/ca.crt; find /minikube"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: harbor-harbor-ingress
        mountPath: "/etc/harbor-certs"
        readOnly: true
        - name: docker-certsd-volume
        mountPath: "/minikube/etc/docker/"
        readOnly: false
    restartPolicy: Never
    volumes:
    - name: harbor-harbor-ingress
        secret:
        secretName: harbor-harbor-ingress
    - name: docker-certsd-volume
        hostPath:
            # directory location on host
            path: /etc/docker/
            # this field is optional
            type: Directory
backoffLimit: 4
END
kubectl apply -f update-docker-registry-trust.yaml
```